# Does a PS Vita get powered by the charger when the battery is full?

Tags: ps-vita

In New Little King's Story, to get the final end you need to rise the affection of all the princesses which can be done by scouting them and just waiting around. This is what I did with Corina while I was doing the Alchemy to get the Summoning Seals (which took 3 hours each)

During that time I kept an eye on the battery level so that if it got low on power I( would plug it back up and charge it, when I play any other game and I'm charging it I am normally pressing the home button to check the battery indicator and see if it's full (all green and don't have the lighting in it)

I do this as I am afraid of overcharging the battery however I am wondering, if I'm playing the PS Vita with the charger plugged in and the battery is full, does it switch to use the charger as the power source or am I risking overcharging the battery if I keep playing while it's plugged up?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would assume a modern handheld like PS Vita would definitely have something to prevent overcharging the battery. I have plenty of devices that I leave on charger over night with no ill effects, I'm sure it's a pretty standard thing nowadays for devices to prevent overcharging.

Comment: @Ben Actually you just did the one thing Chrome doesn't do (apart from having 800 tabs open in one window) which is check for capitalization

Comment: Swapping smoothly to direct wall power is not very common, but most devices will simply let the battery drain from 100% to 95% or so before charging resumes, so it's an on-off-on-off sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reasonably safe to leave charger plugged in while playing. Moreover you will keep charge at 100% while playing with charger attached, so yes, most probably it's using charger instead of battery (I know some people play this way to play for a long time).

And as @Chippies mentioned, all modern device-charger pair are configured they can be leaved connected for any reasonable time.